# Refactoring pandas using an iterator via chunksize

Tags: python, pandas, csv, iterator, refactoring

I am looking for advice on using a `pandas` iterator.

I performed a parsing operation using Python `pandas`, the size of the input files (a bioinformatics program called eggNOG) is resulting in 'RAM bottleneck' phenomenon. It's just not processing the file.

The obvious solution is to shift to an iterator, which for `pandas` is the  `chunksize` option

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('myinfile.csv', sep="\t", chunksize=100)
```

Whats changed with the original code is the `chunksize=100` bit, forcing an iterator.

The next step is just to perform a simple operation, dropping a few columns and moving all '-' characters to np.nan then writing the whole file.

```
df.drop(['score', 'evalue', 'Description', 'EC', 'PFAMs'],axis=1).replace('-', np.nan)
df.to_csv('my.csv',sep='\t',index=False)
```

How is this done under a pandas iterator?

---

**Update**

The solution is described in answers below and comprised two components:

1. Don't load junk at point source: I uploaded and deleted lots of junk (not good)
2. Leveraging `open` outside the chunking loop. This forces the outfield to remain open for each chunk to be written and shuts on the last chunk.

The outfile comprised duplicates. Its inevitable because they split across different chunks and these removed, i.e. reduced, via

```
df = df.groupby(['compoundIndex'])['Frequency'].sum().to_frame()
```

This resulted in the outfile being identical to the non-iterator method and by manipulating chunksize any level of "RAM bottleneck" could be overcome. The actual code is an OO module - reasonably complex parsing - and the codes below fitted straight in.

Cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
cols_to_drop = ['score', 'evalue', 'Description', 'EC', 'PFAMs']
data = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv('myinfile.csv', sep='\t', na_values='-', chunksize=100):
    chunk = chunk.drop(columns=cols_to_drop)
    data.append(chunk)
pd.concat(data).to_csv('my.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

If you know the columns you want to keep instead of which ones you want to drop, use:

```
cols_to_keep = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
data = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv('myinfile.csv', usecols=cols_to_keep, usesep='\t', na_values='-', chunksize=100):
    data.append(chunk)
pd.concat(data).to_csv('my.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Alternative inspired by @el_oso:

```
cols_to_drop = ['score', 'evalue', 'Description', 'EC', 'PFAMs']
with (open('myinfile.csv') as inp,
      open('my.csv', 'w') as out):
    headers = inp.readline().split('\t')
    out.write('\t'.join([col for col in headers if col not in cols_to_drop]))
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(inp, header=None, names=headers, sep='\t', na_values='-', chunksize=100):
        chunk = chunk.drop(columns=cols_to_drop)
        chunk.to_csv(out, sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Thank you and thanks for your quick response. This is simple but cool.

Comment: I'm not sure how much this will help as you're still storing the whole dataframe, albeit with less columns in memory.

Answer (score 1):

if you're already having memory issues reading the file, the below will actually read and write to the new file in chunks.

```
cols_to_keep = {'col1', 'col2', 'col3'}
df = pd.read_csv('myinfile.csv', chunksize=10, usecols=cols_to_keep)
with open('my.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\t'.join(cols_to_keep) + '\n')
    for chunk in df:
        #do your processing here, appending that chunk to the file
        chunk.to_csv(f, header=None, sep='\t')
```

`f` is _io.TextIOWrapper i.e. a stream you can consistently write to in small memory chunks

Comment: This is the solution. I am extremely grateful. Its simplicity is deceptive: it leverages don't load junk and using `open` above the chunking loop. The structure was implemented across a moderately large OO module.  It worked and was identical to the non-iterator approach - described in the **Update** in the question and chunksize manipulation overcame the "RAM bottleneck".